# Dynamically joining rooms in Vue SocketIO

Tags: socket.io, vuejs2

I am using Vue SocketIO on the front end, and would like my application to join rooms dynamically, based on user input.

This feature is not yet available in the package (the author has been working on it,) and I was wondering about ways to hack it together.

I am setting up SocketIO in my main application file like this:

```
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
const socketInstance = io(require('../config/web').socket_url, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
    transportOptions: {
        polling: {
            extraHeaders: {
                Authorization: token
            }
        }
    }
});
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: socketInstance,
    vuex: {
        store,
        actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
        mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_'
    }
}));
```

In my component, I am attempting to join like this,

```
selectSession () {
                console.log(this.$socket)
                // this.$socket.join(this.subscribedSession)
            }
```

which fails since this.$socket has no join method.

Anyone have an idea of how to hack this?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem with the `VueSocketIO` package or even the `socket.io-client`

The `vue.$socket` is a `socket.io-client` instance and therefore has all features the native client provides.

The problem is that you cannot join rooms from the client-side, this is a server-side only feature.

If you look at the [native socket.io client API docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) you will find that there is no `join` method on the client object, not because they have not implemented it but because it can by design not exist

### So how can I fix this then?

I'm glad you asked...

I suggest making a server-side handler named `join` which takes the room name as a argument and then the server joins the socket into the room

```
const express = require("express");
const io = require('socket.io')(express());

io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("join", roomName => {
    socket.join(roomName);
  }
};
```

Then from you client you can use:

```
socket.emit("join", "chatroom1");
```

NOTE: This could potentially be a security problem.

Comment: Thanks. But how do they intend for the clients to join rooms in the first place? Meaning, if my server is emitting on certain rooms, how do my clients know to listen to them?

Comment: You just listen to your server events normally. Rooms only exist on the server, the client has no clue they are in the rooms they are and they shouldn't know. You just listen like you normally would on the client and let the server manage who gets which events.

Comment: If you give me a more concrete example, I could help you more. Rooms are just a abstraction to help you manage clients